# Unable to send Programmable sms to Philippines numbers (Twilio)

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api, twilio-php

am finding it difficult to send an sms to a Philippines number using the example from the Twilio SMS PHP Quickstart documentation...

here's my code

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$account_sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'; /////my account_sid
$auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXX'; ////my auth_token
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$twilio_number = "+XXXXXXXXXXX";////// my twilio_number 
$number = "XXXXXXXXXX"; /////Philippines number 12 digits


$client->messages->create(
          // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
          '+'.$number,
          array(
              'from' => $twilio_number,
              'body' => 'My Twilio Message'
          )
      );
  echo json_encode('done');
```

it works with other countries like the US, Canada etc. At least I've tried those and they work. Anybody with an idea please ?

Comment: What is the error that you get when you try to send the message?

Comment: I don't know how to check for errors, I'm kind of new to the whole thing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting Twilio support, they helped me realize that I had not enabled geo permission to send SMS towards these countries, rookie mistake ...

Any one having this issue, you can click [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions) to enable this setting.